# switch methods in montecarlo objects with brightway

Tags: python-3.x, brightway

I am having trouble to successfully apply `switch_method` to montecarlo objects. I try to switch from a method with uncertainty to one without in a product system without uncertainty and I still get uncertain results.

Hereby an example:

```
pm25_key=('biosphere3', '051aaf7a-6c1a-4e86-999f-85d5f0830df6')

# uncertain method

cfs=[(pm25_key,{"amount": 10,
       "uncertainty type": 4,
       "minimum": 0,
       "maximum": 20}),]

test_method_name_1=('test method Stackoverflow','1 unspecified')
test_method_1=bw.Method(test_method_name_1)
metadata_test_method={'description':'method with 1 uncertain CF',
 'unit':'DALY'}
test_method_1.register(**metadata_test_method)
test_method_1.write(cfs)

# static method

cfs2=[(pm25_key,10)]
test_method_name_2=('test method Stackoverflow','0 unspecified')
test_method_2=bw.Method(test_method_name_2)
metadata_test_method={'description':'method with 0 uncertain CF',
 'unit':'DALY'}
test_method_2.register(**metadata_test_method)
test_method_2.write(cfs2)
```

define a simple product system without uncertainty

```
# test activities 

act1_key=('test_so','activity_1')


biosphere_exchange_1={'amount':1,
                    'input':pm25_key,
                    'output':act1_key,
                    'type':'biosphere',
                    'uncertainty type': 0}

production_exchange_1={'amount':1,
                     'input':act1_key,
                     'output':act1_key,
                     'type':'production',
                     'uncertainty type':0}

act_1_dict={'name':'test_activity_1',
             'unit':'megajoule',
             'exchanges':[production_exchange_1,biosphere_exchange_1]}

# activity 2


act2_key=('test_so','activity_2')

production_exchange_2={'amount':1,
                     'input':act2_key,
                     'output':act2_key,
                     'type':'production',
                     'uncertainty type':0}

technosphere_exchange_1={'amount':10, 
'input':act1_key,
'output':act2_key,
'type':'technosphere',
'uncertainty type':0}

act_2_dict={'name':'test_activity_2',
            'unit':'megajoule',
            'exchanges':[production_exchange_2,technosphere_exchange_1]}

database_dict={act1_key:act_1_dict,
               act2_key:act_2_dict}

db=bw.Database('test_so')
db.write(database_dict)
```

```
mc=bw.MonteCarloLCA({('test_so','activity_2'):1},('test method Stackoverflow','1 unspecified'))
next(mc)
next(mc)
```

I get different results, ok

```
# now try to switch method
mc.switch_method(('test method Stackoverflow','0 unspecified'))
next(mc)
next(mc)
```

I still get different results

```
mc.redo_lcia() 

next(mc) # still uncertain


mc.load_lcia_data()
mc.characterization_matrix.toarray() # this shows a CF of 10 (as expected)
```

but I keep doing `next(mc)` I keep getting different results, when in theory I've switched to a method with no uncertainty and I don't have uncertainty in A or B matrices.. do you know where the problem is ? I am using brightway version 2,3 . with version 3.6.2 of bw2data and 1.8.0 of bw2calc

Comment: Re: "btw I had to put two activities because I got an error trying to run a system of just one element" - please file this as an issue with a reproducible test case.

Comment: Re: "# (it throws an error if demand is not defined)" - Please check to make sure this is true with `bw2calc` version 1.8.0. If so, please file an issue.

Comment: BTW, all BW2 development is not on Github, file issues here: https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2-calc

Comment: I've filed the issue. The second minor comment has been solved with the update. I will update my question.